# Data Frame Export to Excel is not in the Desired Format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

When I try to export the data frame into my output.xlsx file, the date format is in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. My desired output is YYYY-MM-DD (or without time). Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

# create a DataFrame 
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Python\data.xlsx')

#define output path
path = r"C:\Users\Python\output.xlsx"

#print to console to check if read is good
print(df)

#process new data frame from original
CasesperDay_df = df.groupby('Date').agg({'cases':'sum'})

#print to console to check for desired output
print (CasesperDay_df)

#export processed data to output file
CasesperDay_df.to_excel(r"C:\Users\Python\output.xlsx", sheet_name = 'Cases per Day')
```

Here is the output with the undesired result:

[undesired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8MdC.png)

Here is the output that I would like to see:

[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0xmB.png)

This is what I have tried

Inserting a command that would convert the date format from datetime to date

```
import pandas as pd

# create a DataFrame 
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Python\data.xlsx')

#define output path
path = r"C:\Users\Python\output.xlsx"

#print to console to check if read is good
print(df)

#process new data frame from original
CasesperDay_df = df.groupby('Date').agg({'cases':'sum'})

#print to console to check for desired output
print (CasesperDay_df)

#export processed data to output file
CasesperDay_df.to_excel(r"C:\Users\Python\output.xlsx", sheet_name = 'Cases per Day')

#convert date to desired result
CasesperDay_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(CasesperDay_df['Date']).dt.date
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out

Just had to convert the original data frame into the right date format first

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xlsxwriter` as engine with a custom datetime format:

```
# Install xlsxwriter: pip install xlsxwriter
with pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\Python\output.xlsx',
                    datetime_format='M/D/YYYY',
                    engine='xlsxwriter') as xlsx:
    CasesperDay_df.to_excel(xlsx, sheet_name='Cases per Day')
```

Output:
[image]